# Sorting a dict with tuples as values

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{'key_info': (rank, raw_data1, raw_data2),
 'key_info2': ...}
```

Basically I need back a list of the keys in sorted order, that is sorted based on the `rank` field in the tuple.

My code looks something like this right now (`diffs` is the name of the dict above):

```
def _sortRanked(self):
    print(type(self.diffs))
    return sorted(self.diffs.keys(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

that right now returns this when I run it:

```
return sorted(self.diffs.keys(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`keys()` only gives you keys, not values, so you have to use the keys to retrieve values from the dict if you want to sort on them:

```
return sorted(self.diffs.keys(), key=lambda x: self.diffs[x], reverse=True)
```

Since you're sorting on `rank`, which is the first item in the tuple, you don't need to specify which item in the value tuple you want to sort on. But if you wanted to sort on `raw_data1`:

```
return sorted(self.diffs.keys(), key=lambda x: self.diffs[x][1], reverse=True)
```

Comment: I changed it to this, and i get a weird order out of the program now, like in my edited question.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing the key as the argument to, uh, `key`.

```
[k for (k, v) in sorted(D.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)]
```

Comment: You forgot the `reverse=True` part.

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to sort on the keys of the dictionary, not the values. Replace your `self.diffs.keys()` call with `self.diffs.items()`, and then it should work (but do keep the lambda, or use `operator.itemgetter(1)`. Tuples sort starting with the first element, so you don't have to worry about that.)

---

Just noticed that you only want the keys. With my suggestion, you'd have to wrap the sort with `zip()[0]` (making sure to unpack the resultant list of tuples from the sort by prefixing with `*` in the call to `zip()`).

Answer (score 0):

You're close.  Try this instead:

```
return sorted(self.diffs.keys(), key = lambda x: self.diffs[x][0], reverse = True)
```

You're sorting a list of keys, so you have to take that key back to the dictionary and retrieve element 1 in order to use it as a comparison value.

Comment: this does work, however it seems to be sorting in a non-sensical order...

`P : 3.11612504885e-05 1528 4
C : 2.50018364323e-05 2316 7
Q : -3.49014288804e-05 152 2
T : -4.45535602789e-05 2623 11
Z : -0.000101817241062 491 6`