# How do I sort a dictionary by value if my value is a tuple?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, lambda, tuples

I want to sort by the 2nd index value of the tuple and the tuple is the value for the given dictionary.

Here is the given dictionary:

```
dict={'123456789': ('*2L 2% Vitali Mil', 47, '(780) 789 0123', 121.26), '123456798': ('*1L 2% Vitali Mil', 41, '(780) 890 7654', 59.45)}
```

I need to sort this by the phone number ie `'(780) 789 0123'` and `'(780) 890 7654'`

I tried `sorted(dict.items, key=lambda item: item[1][2])` but this gives me an error when I use the the format method for my program.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please submit a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), ie. show an example and expected output

Comment: `{k: v for k, v in sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1][2])}` This will sort the dictionary based on `phone number` in your dictionary

Comment: This question was in the reopen queue, and I'm inclined to leave it closed even after the edit since it's not the first time this kind of question gets asked here. See, for example, [Sorting a dict with tuples as values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6349296/7851470).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `sorted()` - note the difference between my example and yours is that mine sorts the result of the `d.items()` method, which returns a list of key-value tuples, while yours attempts to sort `d.items`, which is a reference to the function itself. We can also format the result as a dictionary using a dictionary-comprehension; for example:

```
>>> d = {'123456798': ('*1L 2% Vitali Mil', 41, '(780) 890 7654', 59.45),
         '123456789': ('*2L 2% Vitali Mil', 47, '(780) 789 0123', 121.26)}

>>> sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: item[1][2])
[('123456789', ('*2L 2% Vitali Mil', 47, '(780) 789 0123', 121.26)),
 ('123456798', ('*1L 2% Vitali Mil', 41, '(780) 890 7654', 59.45))]

>>> {k: v for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: item[1][2])}
{'123456789': ('*2L 2% Vitali Mil', 47, '(780) 789 0123', 121.26),
 '123456798': ('*1L 2% Vitali Mil', 41, '(780) 890 7654', 59.45)}
```

Note also, that you should not use the builtin `dict` variable to name your dictionaries - doing so overwrites the `dict` class, so if you try to use `dict()` in future, the results will not be as expected.